# Can't convert system.windows.forms.messageboxbuttons to system.windows.messageboxbuttons

Tags: c#, .net

I can't do a message on my C# wpf project, I have imported all asembly but now reciving this serror

the MessageBoxButtons have an error "Cant convert system.windows.forms.messageboxbuttons to system.windows.messageboxbuttons"

```
using System.Windows;
using System;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Security;
using MessageBox = System.Windows.MessageBox;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;



      if (MessageBox.Show("test", "Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
                    {
                        // user clicked yes
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // user clicked no
                    }
```

Comment: WPF or Windows Forms? I ask becaise System.Windows.MessageBox is WPF and System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox is forms. You should use (`using`) only the one relevant to your code to avoid confusion

Comment: You have a using up there for System.Windows.Forms. What happens if you remove the reference? It sorta conflicts with using MessageBox = System.Windows.MessageBox;

Comment: Remove the `s`: `MessageBoxButton.YesNo`

Comment: You are mixing Winforms and WPF code here, You've aliased MessageBox, so that is using the WPF variant, but the rest is Winforms, which won't work together.

Comment: it is WPF application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mixed WPF/Winforms

Use the right namespace for buttons/Images :

```
if (MessageBox.Show("test", "Confirm", System.Windows.MessageBoxButton.YesNo, System.Windows.MessageBoxImage.Question) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
{
    // user clicked yes
}
else
{
    // user clicked no
}
```

Comment: cant differenciate which is of wpf or winform, anyway that worked, thanks!